# Spacewalk 2.10 add ubuntu client 16.04 18.04 20.04

Tags: server

I have installed a spacewalk server 2.10 and created channels and repositories for my ubuntu servers 16.04, 18.04, 20.04.

How can I connect my ubuntu servers  16.04 18.04 20.04 to my spacewalk server 2.10?

Thanks in advance.

Best regards ;)

Comment: Ok I have edited the post. Thank you

Comment: according to their website 
"Spacewalk supports Fedora 30 and 31, Red Hat Enterprise Linux and CentOS 8 clients"

Comment: Here is a link that may help you build it yourself https://github.com/spacewalkproject/spacewalk/blob/master/client/debian/DEBIAN-HOWTO